# What dialogue would a crop duster typically have with ATC?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, visual-flight-rules, aerial-application

[image]
By Stefan Krause, Germany (Own work) [[FAL](http://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en)], [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AGehling_PLZ106AR_Kruk_OTT_2013_D7N9017_009.jpg)

What is the exact dialogue a [crop duster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_application) pilot will have, if any, with ATC on a routine flight?

Comment: Are you wanting to know everything from startup to shutdown, or just part of the flight? Also, what country or area are you interested in?

Comment: What? Crop dusters with radios? What is this world coming to? Hmm, maybe I'm a little out of date. The last time I was in a crop duster was in 1956.

Comment: The [current answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29055/crop-dusting-dialogue-with-atc/29056#29056) and its comment show that this is actually possible to answer this question easily. VTR.

Comment: Typically, no communication will take place with *ATC*, because most crop dusting will take place in uncontrolled airspace, or at least outside of airspace requiring communication with ATC. However, it is not uncommon for a crop duster to do some traffic advisory communication over CTAF if operating out of a public use airport. In my flights in the vicinity of crop dusters and crop dusting operations, I have heard CTAF traffic calls on a few occasions, at what I would estimate to be 10% of operations at public use airports.

Answer (score 3):

The actual *operation* of a crop duster airplane will almost invariably happen in uncontrolled airspace. In the US, controlled airspace does not start until 700, 1200, or in a very few select areas 14,500 feet above ground level; below that the airspace is Class G, uncontrolled. Crop dusters operate at a few hundred feet above ground level or lower (a quick google shows altitude as low as a few tens of feet AGL). Even if they wanted to talk to ATC at those altitudes, radio reception would be all but impossible.

When not actually working on a field crop dusters must adhere to the standard minimum altitude rules (500 feet AGL over non-congested areas, or 1000 feet above the tallest obstruction within 2000 feet over congested areas). But even if they enter Class E airspace, which is controlled, they do not have to contact ATC unless they want to receive an instrument flight rules clearance.

There are three times when a crop duster would have a dialog with ATC: when they want to come into a controlled airport to land, when they want to transition the airspace close to a controlled airport (where the controlled airspace extends to the surface), or when they want to operate over a field within the controlled airspace near an airport. For the first two situations they would communicate with the tower just like any other aircraft; for the last situation it might sound like this:

> **Duster:** Podunk Tower, hello, Air Tractor 123AT is eight miles to the east, we'd like to operate over a field inside the Class Delta airspace two miles east of Podunk Airport.
> **Tower:** Air Tractor 123AT, Podunk Tower, the Podunk altimeter 2992, proceed as requested and remain east of runway 18/36.
> **Duster:** Proceed as requested, remain east of 18/36, Air Tractor 3AT.